# Autocompleting only the place name with Google places API

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dictionary

I have successfully setup autocomplete of Google Places API with

```
var input = document.getElementById('place_name');
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
```

But that automatically fills the textbox **place_name** with full address like "ABC, Some Street, Washington, WA, United States"
But I want to fill the textbox with only the place name e.g. **ABC** in my case.
How I can do that?

I tried

```
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function () {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    $('#place_name').val(place.name);
});
```

but it didn't do anything.
Help please...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I now realize I completely misinterpreted the question. I thought it was the content of the dropdown box you wanted to sanitize. To change content of the searchbox, just add

```js
input.value=input.value.split(',')[0];
```

to your `place_changed` event -> **http://jsfiddle.net/9RkM9/**

---

This is how google maps places organizes the results (predictions) in the dropdown box :
[image]

Google does not [guarantee](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#style_autocomplete) this structure to be stable in all future, but the fact they actually document the markup structure proofs we can trust it for now.

A typical `.pac-item` will look like this, here searching for "Los" :

```html
<div class="pac-item">
    <span class="pac-item-query"><span class="pac-matched">Los</span>
    Altos</span><span>CA, United States</span>
</div>
```

Here with `CA` and `United States` present, which you want to avoid. The task is simply to reduce the content of the `.pac-item` node, so we only keep the name part of the socalled *prediction*. The autocomplete searches each and every time the user hits a key, so you can overrule the autogenerated list of predictions on your own `input` `keyup` event. There need to be a little delay, so we actually access the newest list of predictions, not the previous one :

```js
input.onkeyup = function(e) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      var places = document.querySelectorAll('.pac-item');      
      for (var i=0;i<places.length;i++) {
         var place = places[i];
         //get the icon
         var pac_icon = place.querySelector('.pac-icon').outerHTML;
         //get the mathed name only, including markup for precise match, loke "Los" in bold 
         var place_name_reduced = place.querySelector('.pac-item-query').outerHTML;
         place.innerHTML = pac_icon + place_name_reduced;
      }
   }, 150);
}
```

See it in action here  ->  **http://jsfiddle.net/8SGvR/**

Comment: That's nice david. But the code is too long as compared to the task i want to do. I just have the above stated code and it is fulfilling my task, just one thing i require that input.onkeyup value is changed. but when i am using jquery it's not working in the eventListener part

Comment: @MohanSinfh ??? jQuery does not prevent the above from working, how should it do so? You have the `input`, exactly as in the first fiddle (the update in the top) just insert  `input.value=input.value.split(',')[0];` as the first line in your _non-jQuery listener_ `google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed'function () {` ... Yes, the second part is "too long", but this was also regarding the dropdown :)  You can completely skip `onkeyup` part, the mentioned line is all what you need to do the trick. Sry, it may somehow be confusing that I just reused the fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Use address array. It has address in pieces. Just take what you need.

```
place.address_components
```

To see whats in this array, use console:

```
console.log(place.address_components);
```

For example, to update value of input

```
$('#place_name').val(place.address_components[0].long_name);
```

Comment: I already tried this, but the the value is not getting changed

Answer (score 0):

```
const options = {
    componentRestrictions: { country: "az" },
    fields: ["geometry", "name"],
    origin: map.getCenter(),
    strictBounds: false,
    types: ["establishment"],
};

const input = document.getElementById('#txtHotels');
const autocompleteHotels = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

google.maps.event.addListener(autocompleteHotels, 'place_changed', function () {
    var near_place = autocompleteHotels.getPlace().name;
    input.value = near_place;
});
```